# sudo apt-get install build-essential does not work

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu

`sudo apt-get install build-essential` does not work in my ubuntu 12.04.

when I tried to install it does not work.

Comment: That's a bit wierd. Ok, tell us which version of Ubuntu 12.04 are you using( 32 bit or 64bit).

Comment: What did you get when you tried to install it?

Comment: it should work... do you have tried apt-get update before your apt-get install... ?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include the complete and exact text of *everything* that happens in the Terminal, starting with the line on which you enter the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. (If you don't still have it up, then run the command again to get this text.) Also, please clarify in your question if the problem is that you are unable to install it, or that you cannot use the software once it is installed. Please give as detailed a description as possible of what you are attempting to achieve by running this command.

Answer (score 4):

You should run
`sudo apt-get update` and then try again.

A similar issue was found in the Ubuntu forums[[http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11942951]](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11942951).